# Entity Framework Code First Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

We are using Entity Framework code first migration technique for a while now. Everything works good however our Migrations folder has been growing big with numerous migration files because of changes we are making on entity schema. I was curious, is there a way we can update just one or specific number of files whenever there is change in entity so that our Migrations folder would look less messy. Also, i don't want to drop the table and recreate it since i will be loosing all the saved data.

Comment: See Chris's blog here about rolling up your migrations: http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Answer (score 4):

You could simply merge all of your migrations into a new file (if you aren't concerned with keeping every migration).

To do so, simply delete every migration currently in the folder, and rerun the enable-migrations command and then the add-migration command like so.

```
Enable-Migrations

add-migration InitialCreate
```

Comment: how does this work when you deploy it to customers who have a previous schema? It will fail and say objects already exist for most items in the Up()

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use database initializer called MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion. That automatically updates the database schema, when your model changes without losing any existing data or other database objects.

```
Database.SetInitializer(
new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourDbContext, 
DataLayer.Migrations.Configuration>());
```