# Conditionally inserting data in a code-first migration with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, code-first

I am trying my 2nd migration using the Entity Framework, and so far I generated code like this

```cs
namespace Entity.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class LedgerDisplayOrder : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("Ledgers", "DisplayOrder", c => c.Int());
            // Hic sunt leones
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("Ledgers", "DisplayOrder");
        }
    }
}
```

The logic how to fill this column is actually pretty simple, in SQL it would be something like the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [Ledgers] ADD [DisplayOrder] INT NULL;

UPDATE [Ledgers] 
SET DisplayOrder = 10 
WHERE [Id] = 26 OR [Id] = 27 OR [Id] = 23; 

UPDATE [Ledgers] 
SET DisplayOrder = 20 
WHERE [Id] = 29 OR [Id] = 9; 

UPDATE [Ledgers] 
SET DisplayOrder = 30 
WHERE [Id] = 28 OR [Id] = 23;
```

In other words, the migration should automatically be populated during the migration, but I am not sure what to put at `// hic sunt leones` to achieve just that. I read that I should use the [migrationBuilder class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder?view=efcore-3.1), probably something like

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(table: "ledger", column: "DisplayOrder", value: "10");
```

but how to implement the `WHERE` clause? And how do I load that class? My Visual Studio's *Quick Actions and Refactoring*  keeps suggesting to implement a new class, so do I have to install something first?

Any help is appreciated!

References: all I found so far is about setting default values for a new column. That's not what I am after.

- [Entity Framework Code First Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872522/entity-framework-code-first-migration)
- [Entity framework core, code first migration with data migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623183/entity-framework-core-code-first-migration-with-data-migration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [migrationBuilder.Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.sql?view=efcore-3.1) command to execute pure SQL-expressions during migration:

Instead of `InsertData` you could use

```cs
Sql("UPDATE [Ledgers] 
     SET DisplayOrder = 10 
     WHERE [Id] = 26 OR [Id] = 27 OR [Id] = 23; ");
```

This is short for `migrationBuilder.Sql` which can be loaded via

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
```

if you are using EF Core or (in your case) by

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
```

if you are using EntityFramework.

Comment: You should add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;` to your header if you are using EF Core or `using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;` if you are using EF.

Comment: Yes, I took my example from EFCore project, where `migrationBuilder` presents as an parameter in `Up()/Down()` functions. Please sorry for my inaccuracy.